# React-redux Provider store = undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, connect

Добрый день помогите решить проблему 3 день ломаю голову выдает ошибку на undefined store[image: в Provider.js]

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import store from "./redux/store-redux"
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';




let rerenderEntrieTree = (store) => {

  ReactDOM.render(

    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store ={store}>
      <App  />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

rerenderEntrieTree();

store.subscribe( () => {

  rerenderEntrieTree()
});
reportWebVitals();
```

MyPostContainer.js

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addPostCreateAction, updatePostTextCreateAction } from '../../../redux/profile-reducer';
import MyPost from './MyPost';

let mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
    newPostText: store.newPostText,
    post: store.post
  }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addPost: () => {
      dispatch(addPostCreateAction());
    },
    onPostChange: (text) => {
      let action = updatePostTextCreateAction(text)
      dispatch(action);
    }
  }
}

const MyPostContainer = () => connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(MyPost);

xport default MyPostContainer;
```

redux-store.js

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import dialogsReducer from "./dialogs-reducer";
import profileRuducer from "./profile-reducer";
import sidebarReducer from "./sidebar-reducer";


export let redusers = combineReducers({
   profilePage:profileRuducer,
   dialogsPage:dialogsReducer,
   sidebarPage:sidebarReducer
});

let store = createStore(redusers);



export default store;
```

dialogs-reducers.js

```js
const sendMessageText = "SEND-MESSAGE-TEXT";
const changeMessageText = "CHANGE-MESSAGE-TEXT";

let initialState =  {
    dialog: [
        { id: 1, name: "Alex" },
        { id: 2, name: "Dasha" },
        { id: 3, name: "Oleg" },
        { id: 4, name: "Tamara" },
        { id: 5, name: "Igor" },
        { id: 6, name: "Lisa" },
    ],
    messages: [
        { message: "Hi", id: 1 },
        { message: "my", id: 2 },
        { message: "name", id: 3 },
        { message: "is", id: 4 },
        { message: "Alex", id: 5 },
        { message: "Yo", id: 6 }
    ],
    newMessageBody: "",
};

const dialogsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case sendMessageText:
            let body = state.newMessageBody;
            state.messages.push({ message: body, id: 6 });
            state.newMessageBody = "";
            return state;
        case changeMessageText:
            state.newMessageBody = action.body;
            return state;
        default: return state;
    }


}


export const changeMessageCreator = (body) =>
({
    type: changeMessageText,
    body: body,
})

export const sendMessageCreator = () => ({ type: sendMessageText })

export default dialogsReducer;
```

Provider.js

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ReactReduxContext } from './Context';
import { createSubscription } from '../utils/Subscription';
import { useIsomorphicLayoutEffect } from '../utils/useIsomorphicLayoutEffect';

function Provider(_ref) {

  var store = _ref.store,
      context = _ref.context,
      children = _ref.children;
  var contextValue = useMemo(function () {
    var subscription = createSubscription(store);
    subscription.onStateChange = subscription.notifyNestedSubs;
    return {
      store: store,
      subscription: subscription
    };
  }, [store]);
  var previousState = useMemo(function () {
    return store.getState();
  }, [store]);
  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(function () {
    var subscription = contextValue.subscription;
    subscription.trySubscribe();

    if (previousState !== store.getState()) {
      subscription.notifyNestedSubs();
    }

    return function () {
      subscription.tryUnsubscribe();
      subscription.onStateChange = null;
    };
  }, [contextValue, previousState]);
  var Context = context || ReactReduxContext;
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Context.Provider, {
    value: contextValue
  }, children);
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Provider.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.shape({
      subscribe: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      getState: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }),
    context: PropTypes.object,
    children: PropTypes.any
  };
}

export default Provider;
```

В провайдере показывает _ref:undefined

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

rerenderEntrieTree не нужно

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import store from "./redux/store-redux"
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App  />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0):

В connect нужно поменять местами mapDispatchToProps и mapStateToProps, т.е. должно быть:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```